# Can I shorten this assembly code to test if a number is even?

Tags: performance, assembly

Here is MIPS code to return 1 if a number is even, 0 otherwise:

```
isEven:
  andi $t0, $a0, 1
  li   $t1, 1
  sub  $v0, $t1, $t0
  jr   $ra
```

My question is whether this can be done in fewer instructions. I could implement `isOdd` in two instructions (by eliminating the `li` and `sub`), but I don't see a single-instruction way to invert just the bottom bit of `$t0` into `$v0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was helpfully pointed out by G. Sliepen in a comment, you can flip the bottom bit using xor.

That enables the above code to be rewritten in one fewer instruction:

```
isEven:
  andi $t0, $a0, 1
  xori $v0, $t0, 1
  jr   $ra
```

This takes advantages of the properties:

```
A xor 1 = !A
A xor 0 = A
```

Comment: sub or add 1 also flips the low bit, and can be done before `and`.  You can do the same 2-instruction trick even on x86 where one of the only copy-and-operate instructions is LEA.  A similar question came up on Stack Overflow not long after this: [Check if a number is even](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64113177).

Comment: MIPS can also implement bitwise NOT with `nor $v0, $zero, $a0`, so `return (~x)&1` also works.  Also, don't forget to try asking a compiler for micro-optimization ideas: https://godbolt.org/z/Trd8TG shows that gcc (and clang) know this trick for MIPS, using andi/xori for `return x%2 == 0` for unsigned x.

Comment: @PeterCordes Perhaps both questions were inspired by this tweet: https://twitter.com/ctrlshifti/status/1288745146759000064?lang=en